# Cannot get data from object in Angualr

Tags: angularjs, ngrx

I am currently writing an app using Angular, NgRx and angular fire. I have managed to get the data and can console.log the data which returns an object, however, I cannot access the object data

I store the data in a User model

```
    export interface User {
        userID: string;
        email: string;
        firstname: string;
        lastname: string;
    }
```

Then in the component returning the data, I create an observable and populate it within ngOnInit

```
    currentUser$:Observable<User>;

    ...
    
    ngOnInit(): void {
     
        this.currentUser$ = this.store.select(fromRoot.getUserDetails);   
        
        this.currentUser$.subscribe(user => {
          console.log(user)
        })   
       
      }
```

This returns in the console

```
    {userID: "xjZ1aqcPFDOAMappYHgMqcYjQie2", email: "jonathansiberry@gmail.com", firstname: "Jonathan", lastname: "Siberry"}
    email: "jonathansiberry@gmail.com"
    firstname: "Jonathan"
    lastname: "Siberry"
    userID: "xjZ1aqcPFDOAMappYHgMqcYjQie2"
```

However when changing it to

```
    console.log(user.firstname)
```

I am shown the error

```
    core.js:6162 ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'firstname' of null
        at SafeSubscriber._next (header.component.ts:37)
        at SafeSubscriber.__tryOrUnsub (Subscriber.js:183)
        at SafeSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:122)
        at Subscriber._next (Subscriber.js:72)
        at Subscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
        at DistinctUntilChangedSubscriber._next (distinctUntilChanged.js:50)
        at DistinctUntilChangedSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
        at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
        at MapSubscriber.next (Subscriber.js:49)
        at MapSubscriber._next (map.js:35)
```

I tried to parse with JSON but as user in the subscription is of type User it cannot convert to a string

Why can I not access the values within the user object?

Answer (score 1):

When you print the whole user in the console do you see a null printed first? If so, it means that your store emits a null user at first so you might need to perform a null check or use the optional chaining operator:

```
console.log(user?.firstname)
```

Answer (score 0):

> this.currentUser$.subscribe(user => {
> console.log(user)
> })

In this try to use **any** similar to below code:

```
this.currentUser$.subscribe(user: any => {
   console.log(user);
})
```

Also, try to assign the returned value to another variable and then try to access it.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks, it seems the value is being set but not at that moment I am outputting to the console, i.e. outputting to the console returns null but referencing the variable in the HTML file works suggesting timing issues (it is an async function I guess)

Due to this, I am completing the request. Thanks, guys for your help